# Flex setting -swf-version manually breaks NetGroup

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, netgroup

I have a Fullscreen Immersive ane for a flex mobile android application where I have to set `-swf-version=28` to make it compile. Once I do this, the code for my peer2peer communication breaks. 
`NetConnection.Connect.Success` fires then I set up a GroupSpecifier and NetGroup where `NetGroup.Connect.Success` also fires.

`NetGroup.Neighbor.Connect` is the event which isn't triggered anymore.

Two questions:

Why do I have to set the -swf-version manually to use the ane?
(included native extension 'com.mesmotronic.ane.fullscreen' includes a SWF version 28 which is greater than the version of the root SWF of this application: 14)

Why does the NetGroup break when I change the swf version?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By forcing the newer SDK with the additional compiler argument I of course used a newer SDK. Using the same SDK for the Server Application did the trick. Messaging is working again.

Also I switched to Apache SDK so I don't need the additional argument anymore.